# Persist property to following middlewares in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My express app has some auth middleware which determines the current user from the session ID. I want to "persist" the user through to the following middlewares. I've tried attaching the user object to the `res` object, but this doesn't work (presumably because JS doesn't pass function arguments by reference).

I realise that something like [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) handles this specific scenario for you, but I'm interested in solving the general problem of persisting a value through to all subsequent middlewares.

The fact that I can't find any references to this on SO or elsewhere leads me to believe I'm trying to do something Fundamentally Wrong™ so please feel free to call me out. I'd love to hear alternative design approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something called locals

`res.locals`

for example in your case you can set

```
res.locals.id = 'something'
```

this value will persist throughout the request in all middlewares, until the response is sent.

Comment: How did I miss that in the documentation? Thanks so much :)